What's the difference: 74LS04 vs. 74LS04P
Other than the "P" at the end, what's the difference between these:  74LS04 vs. 74LS04P?

What manufacturer?

Did you you look at the ordering code/nomenclature?

Haven't looked to order as yet.

It depends on the manufacturer of the IC what the letter 'P' means.
In general, there is no difference, and the 'P' means the 74LS04 is in Plasic DIP package instead of some other package.

Thanks for the clarification!
